# How can a declared C function have no implementation?

Tags: c

I am baffled by the lack of implementation code for the function glade_project_get_type in the following code snippets.

From the .c file:

```
project = g_object_new (GLADE_TYPE_PROJECT, NULL);
```

From the associated header file:

```
#define GLADE_TYPE_PROJECT   (glade_project_get_type ())
```

This appears to be the declaration of `glade_project_get_type()`:

```
GType  glade_project_get_type (void) G_GNUC_CONST;

/* From glib/gmacros.h:
    #define G_GNUC_CONST    __attribute__((__const__))

    __attribute__((const)) function attribute
 Many functions examine only the arguments passed to them and have no effects 
 except for the return value. 
 If a function is known to operate only on its arguments then it can be subject
 to common sub-expression elimination and loop optimizations.
*/
```

Nowhere can I find the implementation code for glade_project_get_type() but the software compiles without error, so obviously there is something that I don't understand.

I expected there to be something somewhere like:

```
GType  glade_project_get_type (void)
{
  GType aType;

  < some code giving a value to aType >
  return aType
}
```

So, what don't I understand about C programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code implementing `glade_project_get_type` is in the library `libgladeui`, which is compiled separately and linked with the `glade` executable.

The source code for `libgladeui` is shipped along with that of `glade`.  The definition of the function `glade_project_get_type` is in the file `glade-project.c`.  You won't find the string `glade_project_get_type` in that file because the actual code for the function is the result of a complicated macro expansion, coming from the following lines of `glade_project_get_type`:

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_CODE (GladeProject, glade_project, G_TYPE_OBJECT,
                         G_ADD_PRIVATE (GladeProject)
                         G_IMPLEMENT_INTERFACE (GTK_TYPE_TREE_MODEL,
                                                glade_project_model_iface_init)
                         G_IMPLEMENT_INTERFACE (GTK_TYPE_TREE_DRAG_SOURCE,
                                                glade_project_drag_source_init))
```

This macro is defined in the header files for `glib`, specifically `gobject/gtype.h`.  At some point in its expansion, I would guess that [token pasting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) (the `##` preprocessor directive) will be used to take one of the tokens passed to the macro (here `glade_project`) and define a function whose name is that token concatenated with `_get_type`.

Here is a simple example of what is going on here:

```
#define MAKE_FUNC(name, val) int my_ ## name ## _function (void) { return val; }

MAKE_FUNC(magic, 42)

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", my_magic_function());
  return 0;
}
```

Although at first glance, the program doesn't appear to include a definition of `my_magic_function`, the macro `MAKE_FUNC` actually expands to create it.  The expansion of `MAKE_FUNC(magic, 42)` is simply

```
int my_magic_function(void) { return 42; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation which helps a lot but I still lack a full understanding. I found "the following lines of glade_project_get_type" in glade-project.c but don't understand  how they are related to glade_project_get_type().  Is there some book that describes this mechanism as I can't find any description in any of my books?

Comment: After further searching it seems the main source of information is the GObject Reference manual?

Comment: @Roger: Probably.  I'm afraid I don't know anything about how glade works in general.  I was just looking to address your question about how this code compiles, but I can't help with how to actually use it.  You may want to ask a new question.

Comment: That's fine Nate. Your answer has really helped me understand what's going on. I am making some progress now to understanding further the mechanism and imagine that the particular mechanism used here has been defined by the Glade development group as part of their particular methodolgy for developing the Glade system. In effect macros, such as the one in your example seem to be C's method of defining generics.

Answer (score 2):

The function `glade_project_get_type()` is compiled into a library, e.g. `libglade`. The raw source code of this library doesn't contain a definition exactly, because the source code for this function is generated from a template, which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/GNOME/glade/blob/47bf92b0a77e8eea9b6d4b66954f246e630f5383/gladeui/gladeui-enum-types.c.template).

The headers you are using only describe the functions available. Headers rarely contain actual source code in C, they generally just contain function and type definitions. The compiler uses the information in the header to know what return types and argument types the functions has or what members are in a struct or union. It is the linker's job to actually make sure the functions you are using have definitions. The linker will link your source code with the precompiled `libglade` library and connect everything up.

Comment: I presume that glade/gladeui/gladeui-enum-types.c.template and glade/gladeui/gladeui-enum-types.h.template are used to generate gladeui-enum-types.c and gladeui-enum-types.h which I have studied in detail. gladeui-enum-types.h contains many _get_type function definitions such as for glade_pointer_mode_get_type but I cannot locate one for glade_project_get_type.